# how to duplicate a form action programatically

Tags: 8, forms

when a form action takes place, it posts the fields and also redirects to that page, right?  I need to make a custom form do the same, I have successfully made it post the fields in my drupal 8 custom module , using an http request with guzzle, but how do i make it redirect simultaneously as well?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about code the OP wrote but that isn't shown. For questions about code, we expect the question to show the code.

Answer (score 1):

In your submit handler:

```
$form_state->setRedirect($route_name, $parameters, $options);
```

Or if you have a URL object:

```
$form_state->setRedirectUrl($url);
```

Reference:

- [`FormState::setRedirect`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormState.php/function/FormState%3A%3AsetRedirect/8.3.x)
- [`FormState::setRedirectUrl`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormState.php/function/FormState%3A%3AsetRedirectUrl/8.3.x)

Comment: Hi thanks, if I just have the URL as a string, what parameters and options do I have to put in?

Comment: Something like `$url = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromUri('http://google.com');`

Comment: I gott this error Redirects to external URLs are not allowed by default, use \Drupal\Core\Routing\TrustedRedirectResponse for it.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot about the unwilling API. See this comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/2599342#comment-10484496 for a code example, but read the rest of the issue for context too

Comment: I tried this but my response is a guzzle object, so it doesnt like it $form_state->setResponse($response);

Comment: TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Drupal\Core\Form\FormState::setResponse() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response, instance of GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response given,

Comment: Don't use the guzzle response, create a new response per the examples in the linked issue

Comment: But I need a guzzle response to get the form fields over there.  how can I do both?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the question. The guzzle request/response is not related to the Drupal response, they're completely separate

Comment: Oh ok so I can do both ?

Comment: Yes, see the comments above

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what the example code you are referring to is, is it this ?   if (!$form_state->getResponse() && $redirect = $this->redirectForm($form_state)) {
      $form_state->setResponse($redirect);
    }